# using multiple table in hibernate, problem with output

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am using following query

```
from A as a,B as b,C as c where a.val='1' and b.val=a.val and c.val=b.val
```

Now if i do follow

```
query.list();
```

what will be the output?

Also if I want to get the output of above query what else I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
select a from A as a 
join fetch B as b 
join fetch C as c 
where a.val='1' 
and b.val=a.val 
and c.val=b.val
```

You can use join.

```
return List<A>
```

you can use `a.getB().get`.... to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not the right way.For this you have to write nested query Using Criteria.That will be something like as follows:

```
 String query="from A a where a.val in (select b.val from B b where b.val in (select c.val from C c where c.val='1'))";    
 Criteria criteria = session.getSession().createCriteria(TableName.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(query));
   List<tableNameObj> tableNameObj=criteria.list();
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: this query will not provide me data from table B but i require data form table B and C also to be Listed with Table A... so i think this query will not work

Comment: Ohh....then the query which you write is perfect.It is might be giving you null result as one of the table from A,B or C doest not having that record.

Comment: the query is running very fine its giving me the output as object[] with objects of A,B,C and all these tables are mapped with foreign key there is not chance of null.....

Answer (score 0):

From the Hibernate Reference Documentation:

> #### [14.2. The from clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from)
>
> ...
>
> Multiple classes can appear, resulting
>   in a cartesian product or "cross"
>   join.
>
> ```
> from Formula, Parameter
>
> from Formula as form, Parameter as param
> ```

So your query will return a cartesian product and if there are X matching rows in A, Y matching rows in B, Z matching rows in C, you'll get X * Y * Z results (and the product can become huge very quickly).

Be **very** careful with this kind of queries, they are very greedy with resources and might cause serious performance problems.

Comment: @abhishekgem84: Please explain your goal in pure english and maybe I'll be able to help.